Dynamic module federation cannot be used to get remoteEntry exports in the window object
I'm setting up a module federated application in which I want to use dynamic module federation.
The remote application has the following webpack.config.json generated through NX:
Remote
const config: ModuleFederationConfig = {
  name: 'master',
  exposes: {
    './Module': './src/remote-entry.tsx',
  },
};

export default composePlugins(
  withNx(),   
  withReact(),
  withModuleFederation(config, { dts: false })
);


While in the host application I'm simply trying to load the component to check what I obtain.
Host
import { init, loadRemote } from '@module-federation/enhanced/runtime';

init({
  name: 'loader',
  remotes: [
    {
      name: 'master',
      entry: 'http://localhost:4202/master/remoteEntry.js',
    },
  ],
});

loadRemote('master/Module').then((value) => console.log(value));

Notice: I tried opening the browser at localhost:4202 and the script remoteEntry.js is available.
Also in the network tab it is retrieved.
However I get this error:

Any idea on what might be the problem? My guess is that it is something related to the scope not being set into the window object, however I couldn't find a solution.

The issue is on the nx configuration. I could not spot the issue, but by switching to vanilla webpack config I was able to make it work
